# How to switch data in listView by clicking on button

Tags: android, firebase, listview, button

I have a fragment with two buttons and one ListView. I want to change content in ListView when I click on button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmHLm.png)
**Logic:**

1. `firstSemesterButton` clicked -> I get data from Firebase with condition if(course==1 && semester==1) -> get names of this subjects in my list
2. `secondSemesterButton` clicked -> I get data from Firebase with condition if(course==1 && semester==2) -> get names of this subjects in my list

**Problem:**
I don't understand how to make data in ListView switch after clicking on the button.

**What I have now:**
I made first task from 'Logic' description for `firstSemesterButton`. In FirstCourseFragment.java I have `getDataFromDBFirstSemester()` for getting data for `firstSemesterButton` and in `onCreateView(...)`.

**My FirstCourseFragment.java**

```
public class FirstCourseFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    // for buttons
    protected MaterialButtonToggleGroup toggleGroup;
    private Button firstSemesterButton, secondSemesterButton;
    private TextView semesterName;

    // for DB
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private String SUBJECT_KEY = "Subjects";

    // for listView
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private List<String> listData;
    private List<Subject> listSubject;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_course, container, false);
        init(view);
        getDataFromDB();
        setOnClickItem();
        return view;
    }

    //initialize variables
    private void init(View view) {

        semesterName = view.findViewById(R.id.nameSemesterFirstCourse);

        //init for list
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listFirstCourse);
        listData = new ArrayList<>();
        listSubject = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //init for toggleGroup
        toggleGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonGroup);

        // init for first semester
        firstSemesterButton = view.findViewById(R.id.firstSemesterButton);
        firstSemesterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        // init for second semester
        secondSemesterButton = view.findViewById(R.id.secondSemesterButton);
        secondSemesterButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //init for DB
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(SUBJECT_KEY);
    }

    // for getting data from db to listView
    private void getDataFromDBFirstSemester() {
        ValueEventListener vListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (listData.size() > 0) listData.clear();
                if (listSubject.size() > 0) listSubject.clear();
                // record data from database from first course, first semester
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Subject subject = ds.getValue(Subject.class);
                    assert subject != null;
                    if (subject.course == 1 && subject.semester == 1) {
                        listData.add(subject.name);
                        listSubject.add(subject);
                    }
                }
                // notify arrayAdapter about changing data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(vListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.firstSemesterButton:
                semesterName.setText("First semester");
                getDataFromDBFirstSemester();
                break;
            case R.id.secondSemesterButton:
                semesterName.setText("Second semester");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setOnClickItem() {
        // go to the next page when item of listView clicked
    }
}
```

**My question:**
Can I somehow modify `getDataFromDBFirstSemester()` and use it for `secondSemesterButton` with reusing my listView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can quickly see, the variables in your query are:

- The semester you want to show data for.
- Maybe the course you want to show the data for?

So if you pass those values as parameters to your function, you end up with a function:

```
private void getDataFromDBForSemester(int semester, int course) {
    ValueEventListener vListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (listData.size() > 0) listData.clear();
            if (listSubject.size() > 0) listSubject.clear();
            // record data from database from first course, first semester
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Subject subject = ds.getValue(Subject.class);
                assert subject != null;
                if (subject.course == course && subject.semester == semester) {
                    listData.add(subject.name);
                    listSubject.add(subject);
                }
            }
            // notify arrayAdapter about changing data
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
        }
    };
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(vListener);
}
```

And now you can call that twice in your `onClick` handler:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.firstSemesterButton:
            semesterName.setText("First semester");
            getDataFromDBForSemester(1, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.secondSemesterButton:
            semesterName.setText("Second semester");
            getDataFromDBForSemester(2, 1);
            break;
    }
}
```

If you need to pass more values, you'd add them to the list of parameters of the function.

Comment: thanks for such elegant solution, it works!